# jQuery UI: datepicker displays incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to show a jQuery datepicker using

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       self.afterSettingTheDate(model, dateGT, view);
       $("#datepicker").hide();
       $("#datepicker").datepicker('hide');
    }
}); 

$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', d);
$("#datepicker").show();
$("#datepicker").datepicker('show');
```

The HTML (attaching the datepicker to a div):

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#datepicker{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    right: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index:1000001;
}
```

The datepicker shows up like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Comment: try correcting your syntax by using this: `$('#TextFieldID').datepicker();`

Comment: I'm not using a text field to show the date picker. I want to use a button instead. On button click I'm calling the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the display methods provided in the datepicker API.

The original element selector and the widget html itself are not the same.

Try:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( "show" );
```

[See API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't show the full code before. Please check the edited version. Also with your code the same problem occurs.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Can get jQuery UI css url from bottom of api docs to use in external resources

Comment: Thanks, issue resolved: I had tbody set to "display: table" in the CSS. Putting it back to "display: table-row-group" fixed it.